# How to type this complicated fraction in latex?

Tags: math-mode, mathtools

As shown in the below screenshot, how could I type this complicated fraction for x_n in problem 5?
[image]

Comment: You can use `\[x_n=k_0+\frac{1}{k_1+\frac{1}{.....}}\]`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try `\cfrac{}{}` command from `amsmath` package.

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}


\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\[
    x_{n} = k_{0} +
        \cfrac{1}{k_{1} +
            \cfrac{1}{k_{2} +
                \cfrac[l]{\substack{1 \\ \vdots}}{k_{n + 1} +
                    \cfrac{1}{k_{n}}}}}
\]

\end{document}
```